# Direct URI access file serving a vue.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express

I've developed a Vue.js app that uses vue-router to route between components. When routing to a different component, the url changes.

```
  const routes = [{
    path: "",
    mode: 'history',
    name: "bla",
    component: Bla,
    ...
  },
  {
    path: "/secondpath"
    ...
  }]
```

There is a button on the UI that uses `<router-link...>` to route to another component which changes path from `/` to `/secondpath`. However, when I directly go to `.../secondpath` on my browser, it returns `404`.

If I run the app in dev environment by `npm run dev` then the above scenario works. If I first build it by `vite build` and then serve the static files using a web server, e.g. `express.js` then I get the issue above.

Serving via `express.js`:

```
const port = process.env.UI_PORT || 3000
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static('dist'))
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

I do have only one `html` file which is the `index.html`. What do I do wrong here? Should I create multiple html files and somehow redirect user to another `html` page, instead of using `<router-link...>`. And how can I do that if that is the issue?

Comment: You didn't configure web server to serve an SPA. It should serve index.html instead of 404

Comment: @EstusFlask You are right. I didn't know how to do that or search for that. Thank you! Am I supposed to delete this question?

Comment: I'd suggest to keep it, dupes are helpful because people visit them when they search for a solution